# How do I use Manual Mocks in jest with __mocks__ folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to use manual mocks as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@krisma/how-to-do-manual-mock-in-jest-unit-testing-b911fd855bc3).  Jest seems to produce the following output:

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: NewAnnotation(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
annotations
 \ NewAnnotation
   \__mocks__
      \NewAnnotation.js
   \NewAnnotation.js
 \ AnnotationModal.js
 \ AnnotationModal.test.js
```

My  `__mocks__\NewAnnotation` looks like this

```
import React from 'react';

export const NewAnnotation = () => (<button id="test">Hello World</button>);

export default NewAnnotation;
```

My `AnnotationModal.test.js` looks like this

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
...
jest.mock('./NewAnnotation');

...

it(`this is an example test`, () => {
  ...
  wrappedAnnotationModal.find("#test").simulate('click');
  ...
});
```

What am I missing?